# How to add "prediction" lines to an existing ggplot without colouring by group of the previous ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data for which I run linear mixed-effect models using different polynomial degrees. I want to show in a plot the points representing my data and colouring by `ID` and also the prediction lines using the different polynomial degrees. However, for the prediction lines, I don't want to consider the `ID`. Below I show a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lme4)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Height =rnorm(500, mean=175, sd=15),
                 Weight =rnorm(500, mean=70, sd=20),
                 ID = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), (500/4)))

mod1 <- lmer(Height ~ Weight + (1|ID), df)
mod2 <- lmer(Height ~ poly(Weight,2) + (1|ID), df)

y.mod1 <- predict(mod1, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 1
y.mod2 <- predict(mod2, data.frame(Weight=df$Weight),re.form=NA) # Prediction of y according to model 2

df <- cbind(df, y.mod1,y.mod2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

head(df)

    Height   Weight ID
1 166.5929 57.96214  A
2 171.5473 50.12603  B
3 198.3806 90.53570  C
4 176.0576 85.02123  D
5 176.9393 39.81667  A
6 200.7260 68.09705  B
```

What I did was, first, plot my data points:

```
Plot_a <- ggplot(df,aes(x=Weight, y=Height,colour=ID)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))

Plot_a
```

[image]

Then, I plotted the "prediction lines" in my plot:

```
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1)) + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2))

Plot_b
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the lines are coloured with different colours. I guess it is due to the `ID` factor. Does anyone know how to plot the lines without colouring using `ID`?

Comment: `inherit.aes = FALSE` or add the line before the colouring aes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set independent colors for lines like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
#Plot 2
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1),color='black') + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2),color='red')
```

Output:

[image]

As additional element, if you want two legends you can play with `fill` and `color` options in `aes()`. Here the code for that approach:

```
#Plot3
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1,color='mod1'),show.legend = T) + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2,color='mod2'),show.legend = T) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Model"))
```

Output:

[image]

If you want to change colors you can check the options in `scale_color_manual()`.

And for further customization:

```
#Plot 4
Plot_b <- Plot_a + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod1,color='mod1'),show.legend = T) + 
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x=Weight, y=y.mod2,color='mod2'),show.legend = T) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0)),
         color=guide_legend(title="Model"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Duck. By the way, do you know how should I do to add a legend indicating to which polynomial degree correspond each line? I mean, I would like to add another legend (apart from `ID`) in which appears a black line with the word `X¹` and a red line with the word `X²`. Do you know a function or something for doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dekike There is a trick for that. You can play with fill and color. Let me check I have a code for that !

Comment: Oh my god!!! Ok, I will wait! If you share the code would be great. Thank you very much Duck.

Comment: @Dekike Just few minutes! I am on that!

Comment: @Dekike I have updated the post. I hope that can be helpful for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @Duck!! You deserve 5 points instead of 1!! You have saved me a lot of time. Thanks again. In my real case I have lines, so I will use five colours. My doubt now is to choose nice colours. This is for doing a scientific paper, so I have to do it well!! Well, thanks again duck. Regards

Comment: @Dekike Great ! If you think this answer was useful you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side in this answer. It is up to you and it is a way to encourage people to continue helping others :)

Comment: Thanks for remembering. I thought I clicked on it!! I have just done it

Comment: @Dekike Many thanks ! And for sure your paper will be awesome. I saw you posted the comment as answer. Could you please erase that so that we keep the rules established by moderators :)

Comment: I was replying you by my movile phone and I made that mistake. However, I couldn't remove the answer from my mobile! I have had to turn on my PC... But thanks for the note.

Comment: I have just tried your code and I think something is wrong since I do not get two legends, I get only one titled "Model" with `IDs` and models mixed. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: @Dekike Did you try with the data you shared? I ran again and the two legends were produced. Maybe some package is producing conflicts. Try a fresh sessión and only load `ggplot2` and `dplyr`